# How to avoid jackson NullNode.asText() returning a "null" string?

Tags: java, jackson

Sometimes we don't need a pojo Class to map a json. just using jsonNode to get some text value from a json.  But why the jackson libirary designed the NullNode.asText return a "null" string, but not null.

```java
String json = "{\"id\":null,\"locationId\":\"abc\", \"intvalue\": 1}";
ObjectMapper mapper = JsonMapper.builder().build();

JsonNode node = ObjectMapper.readTree(json);

isNotEmpty(jsonNode.path("id").asText()) && !"null".equals(jsonNode.path("id").asText())
// do something...
```

Like this scene, the id may be a string or a long value.  if i use path("id").textValue() is not suitable.

when using asText() I need to check the value isEmpty or equals "null" str.   It's so ugly.

I just using IsNotEmpty(var) && !"null".equals(var).

Comment: This allows you to distinguish between a JSON null value and a missing value in the JSON document.

Comment: I think NullNode and MissingNode  no needs to use the asText method to distinguish.

Answer (score 0):

The initial Jackson tree API was suffering from exactly this issue. To overcome missing/null key/node handling, the `path(...)` method was introduced. This method behaves like `get(...)`, but adds a virtual node for missing keys (`MissingNode`) and null values (`NullNode`), so you don't have to deal with a null return reference. You can use the methods `isMissingNode()` and `isNull()` to check for this node type.

See the code bellow which eliminates the null checks (You have to handle null/missing keys anyway. Jackson can't solve that problem):

```java
public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws Exception {
        // Create the object mapper
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Define the string and parse it
        String json = "{\"id\":null,\"locationId\":\"abc\", \"intvalue\": 1}";
        JsonNode rootNode = mapper.readTree(json);

        // Print different nodes
        printType(rootNode, "nonexistingkey");
        printType(rootNode, "id");
        printType(rootNode, "intvalue");

        // And in your case
        System.out.println("===== ID Check =====");
        JsonNode idNode = rootNode.path("id"); // Change it to locationId to see the Good value
        if (idNode.isMissingNode()) {
            System.out.println("id key does not exist");
        } else if (idNode.isNull()) {
            System.out.println("id key does exist but value is null");
        } else if (idNode.isTextual()) {
            System.out.println("Good value: " + idNode.asText());
        }
    }

    public static void printType(JsonNode rootNode, String key) {
        // Get the child node
        JsonNode childNode = rootNode.path(key);
        System.out.println("===== " + key + " =====");
        System.out.println("Is node missing: " + childNode.isMissingNode());
        System.out.println("Is node instanceof MissingNode: " + (childNode instanceof MissingNode)); // MissingNode is a virtual node
        System.out.println("Is node null: " + childNode.isNull());
        System.out.println("Is node instanceof NullNode: " + (childNode instanceof NullNode)); // NullNode is a virtual node
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
===== nonexistingkey =====
Is node missing: true
Is node instanceof MissingNode: true
Is node null: false
Is node instanceof NullNode: false

===== id =====
Is node missing: false
Is node instanceof MissingNode: false
Is node null: true
Is node instanceof NullNode: true

===== intvalue =====
Is node missing: false
Is node instanceof MissingNode: false
Is node null: false
Is node instanceof NullNode: false

===== ID Check =====
id key does exist but value is null
```

Comment: Thanks,  I know the IsNull method can be used for check.  I have exposed method getDetailOfId(String id) method. it must add the check code before invoke.

In some cases, when we simply want to take a json value and assign it to a PoJo object, using the textValue() method with little attention to the field type can result in a "null" string

now i used the asText(null) instead of asText() method. 
it's also so ugly.